# Memory leak using Matlab function in C++

Tags: c++, matlab, memory-leaks, mex

I wrote my own function in Matlab and compiled it as dynamic C++ library. Then invoked this from my actual C++ code in a loop.
As I can see my program is eating all the memory very fast.
I tried to call `clear` method in Matlab function after all calculations but it didn't take any effect on memory efficiency.
Simplified code is below (without all includings because the problem is not with them).

```
void my_function(args)
{

    mwArray sum; //it is a vector of 3 doubles
    mwArray fina(final_function); //final_function is of std::string type
    minimize(1, sum, fina); //minimize is my own Matlab function about which I told before, it returns a vector of 3 variables and puts it into variable "sum"
    double tetta = sum(1);
    double fi = sum(2);
    double d = sum(3);
    ...

}

int main(int argc, char** argv)
{
    if( !mclInitializeApplication(NULL,0) )
    {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize the application.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    if (!libminimInitialize())
    {
        std::cout << "Could not initialize the library.\n";
        exit(1);
    }
    for (x = 0; x < 100000; x++)
    {
        my_function(args);
    }
    libminimTerminate();
    mclTerminateApplication();

}
```

My matlab function looks like there:

```
function xy = minimize(text)
fun = str2func(text);
options = optimset('Display','off','Algorithm','active-set', 'TolFun', 0.001);
lb = [0, -1.6*pi/180, 0];
ub = [22*pi/180, 1.6*pi/180, 50];
x0 = [0, 0, 0];
A = [];
b = [];
Aeq = [];
beq = [];
non1con = [];
xy = fmincon(fun, x0,A,b,Aeq,beq,lb,ub,non1con, options);
clear -regexp ^(?!xy).*;
end
```

Comment: can you provide sample input/output, especially to the MATLAB function?

Comment: I don't understand. Is this your actual code? What is `args`? It is referenced, but never defined... And is your code performing the same minimization 100000 times? If yes, what for? Anyway, matlab is not known for its memory-efficience. Is it possible to terminate the matlab-related part of the code once you're done with it? By the way, that memory probably eaten by `fmincon`, and that's why `clear`ing those minor variables won't help.

Comment: The input to Matlab function is a string variable, formed by GiNaC C++ package (it's a symbolic equation with 3 variables, every time it is different), then it is turned to lambda function using str2fun Matlav function and minimized. I found out that the function str2fun eats all my memory and now I'm searching a package in C++ which can take as input symbolic expression, some constraints and minimize it. Have you any ideas? The problem is with symbolic nature of an equation.

Comment: I'm not sure it's any more efficient than `str2func`, but you can also try `matlabFunction` of the Symbolic Math Toolbox (although it's possible that `matlabFunction` uses `str2func` under the hood). If the function is very complicated, then I'm not sure there's a solution to the problem.